# Turning a string of characters into a hyperlink

Tags: vba, hyperlink

I have searched a ton for an answer to this question and I can't seem to find one that is specific to my needs. I think it might be possible that I am just not understanding how hyperlinks work in VBA.

Currently, I have an array of strings (each representing a separate file on my server), and I want to add a hyperlink to each string that will take it to the file location on my server. I want that string to be hyperlink-ed so when I paste it in to Word or Outlook, it will already be hyperlink-ed. In my mind, it seems like this should be a fairly straight-forward task; you have a string of text, you have a file location, and you want to hyperlink that string of text with the file location.

For example, let's say I have an array like below:

docArray = {"myDoc1", "myDoc2", "myDoc3"}

which contains the names as string of 3 documents.

I have another array with the file location of each doc:

docLocArray = {"C:\Documents\myDoc1.docx", "C:\Documents\myDoc2.docx", 
"C:\Documents\myDoc3.docx"}

The pseudo-code for this would be something like:

Hyperlink.Add(docArray(1), docLocArray(2))

Is there any way I can do something like this, or am I completely misunderstanding how hyperlinks can be used?

I am working in Autodesk Inventor if that is of any relevance to anyone.

Comment: "how hyperlinks work in VBA" - VBA itself doesn't know anything about hyperlinks. How hyperlinks work depend on what API you're coding against; Excel's hyperlinks work one way, Word's hyperlinks could very well work a different way. You're working in Autodesk Inventor, that's great, but that doesn't tell us what API you're coding against. You want to be able to paste it into Word/Outlook - again that's great, but *where do you copy it from*? If Autodesk Inventor doesn't have hyperlinks, you're out of luck. Search the object browser (F2) for "Hyperlink" in the host's library.

Comment: Ok gotcha, that's helpful. I did not know that. I am sort of new to VBA and am learning as I go... I believe I am coding against Inventor's API. I guess I'm not really sure what you mean by "where do you copy it from?" What I am using to place the strings into Word is docWord.Range.InsertAfter ("my string name") if that helps. Sorry if I am being super unclear and not asking things correctly.

Comment: So... if you're writing into a Word document, you're working against the Word API / object model (and Inventor is irrelevant to this question then). [David's answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/43615011/1188513) should get you started then. Just figure out what to replace the `Selection.Range` part with and you'll be good to go.

Comment: Alright, I'll try to mess around with that. Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 1):

Try this in Word:

```
ActiveDocument.Hyperlinks.Add Anchor:=Selection.Range, Address:="C:\Testdir\Testfile.txt", SubAddress:="", ScreenTip:="", TextToDisplay:="MyFile"
```

Then just loop through the arrays for the values of Path and Filename.

Comment: If this answered your question, consider accepting it as an answer.